# Declare an SQL variable of type int * int?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is the following possible in T-SQL?

```
declare @pair int * int
```

Comment: hehe, the answer "no" is too short to post as an answer.

Comment: You can create a table type with two int columns but that stores rows rather than single tuples. or you could create a custom CLR data type with 2 properties.

Comment: @Martin: while that's true it's obviously set oriented rather than a simple tuple; which is why I was asking what the poster was actually trying to solve...

Comment: The CLR one is scalar. Like the geography type has lat and long properties. But agree would be useful to know the reason for the request.

Comment: I'm just learning the language and trying to figure the ways I can express certain concepts or analyze/visualize data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sql Server, [you can create your own data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx).

To simulate a pair, you can [create a user defined table type](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2012/09/19/creating-a-user-defined-table-type/) that contains the two ints:

```
CREATE TYPE Pair AS TABLE
( 
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
);

DECLARE @Pair Pair

INSERT @Pair
VALUES (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) you have to declare a `data_type` and `(int, int)` is not a `data_type`

```
DECLARE 
{{ @local_variable [AS] data_type } | [ = value ] }
```

> data_type
>
> Is any system-supplied, common language runtime (CLR) user-defined table type, or alias >data type. A variable cannot be of text, ntext, or image data type.

Comment: you can create user defined data types, exactly like books online says.

Comment: @MarkKremers The original question was `Is the folllowing possible?`. And the answer is `No`.